# Захват видео из непрерывного потока на низком уровне

Tags: web-camera

Веб-камера cn0314-0v03, в ней идет непрерывный поток данных. Нужно всего один кадр из этого потока. 
Ловлю данные потока и вижу [следующее](http://s017.radikal.ru/i438/1503/2c/3be61815927e.jpg) 
Хочется знать это уже цельная картинка или часть картинки? 
Или может это набор данных с картинкой вместе? Тогда как узнать где начинается картинка

Comment: @Raaur, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, какой язык и технологии используете и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хватал видео прогами Device Monitoring Studio и usb-monitor-pro. Обе на 15 дней бесплатные. Больше понравилась usb-monitor-pro.